# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \int_0^1 f(t)\sin(nt^2)dt$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

**Problem:** Suppose $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Define $a_n=\int_0^1 f(t)\sin(nt^2)dt$. Prove that exists $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}a_n$.

**Attempt:**
I tried rewriting $a_n=\int_0^n \frac{f(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{n}})}{2\sqrt{ny}}\sin(y)dy$. Then I would define $I_k=[\sqrt{k\pi},\sqrt{(k+1)\pi}]$ and get that: $$\int_{[0,(k+1)\pi]}\frac{f(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{n}})}{2\sqrt{ny}}\sin(y)dy=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(y)}{2\sqrt{n}}[\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\frac{f(\frac{\sqrt{y+j\pi}}{\sqrt{n}})}{\sqrt{y+j\pi}}]dy$$
but I do not know if it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt s$ in the integral defining $a_n.$ We get

$$a_n=\int_0^1 \frac{f(\sqrt s)}{2\sqrt s} \sin (ns) \,ds.$$

Since $\dfrac{f(\sqrt s)}{2\sqrt s}\in L^1[0,1],$ the Riemann Lebesgue lemma implies $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Awesome answer.

Comment: @DionelJaime  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not only does $a_n$ converge, but we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2\sqrt{n}\cdot a_n=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(0)$$

and thus by extention

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$

To get this we let $g(x)=f(\sqrt{x})$, since this is just as well an arbitrary real valued function. We note that the **differentiable** functions $k:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|<\infty$ are dense in the full set of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, we we may assume $f$ is of this sort and then use the trial observation that if $\sup|g(x)-k(x)|<\epsilon$ then

$$\left|\int_0^1g(t^2)\sin(nt^2)dt-\int_0^1k(t^2)\sin(nt^2)dt\right|<\epsilon$$

so we can apply epsilon-delta from the density. Note that the compactness of the interval $[0,1]$ is very important for this step.

We can now apply integration by parts on $a_n$ to see that

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\int_0^ng\left(y/n\right)\frac{\sin(y)}{\sqrt{y}}dy\\
&=\left.\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\cdot g\left(y/n\right)\left(\int_0^y\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx\right)\right]_0^n-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\int_0^ng'\left(y/n\right)\left(\int_0^y\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx\right)dy
\end{align*}

It is a well known fact (see, for example, Wolfram Alpha) that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

as $n\to\infty$ we have

$$\left.g\left(y/n\right)\left(\int_0^y\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx\right)\right]_0^n\to \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot g(1)$$

Turning our attention now to the second part of our expression, we note that

$$\frac{1}{n}\int_0^ng'\left(y/n\right)\left(\int_0^y\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)dy$$

tends to $0$ by a simple $\epsilon-\delta$ argument using the boundedness of $g'(y/n)$. This means that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\int_0^ng'\left(y/n\right)\left(\int_0^y\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx\right)dy&\to \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\int_0^ng'\left(y/n\right)dy\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot \left(g(1)-g(0)\right)
\end{align*}

Collecting these results, we get that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2\sqrt{n}a_n=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot g(0)$$

Since $g(0)=k(0)$ we, apply our density argument and we are done.